# Spring Camel application for one run

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am trying to create an application which will be used only in particular cases, from time to time.

scenario is as follows

1. user run an application
2. aplication start with spring-context.xml camel-context.xml
3. Routes from AppRoute.java are created
4. method which use created routes are executed
5. end

However I have a problem because whenever I use `main.run()` I can see that `route` is created however method is not executed. Without `main.run()` method is executed but no `route` is built.

my main:

```
import org.apache.camel.spring.Main;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


public class EgzekutorManual extends Main{
    @Produce(uri="direct:tester")
    static ProducerTemplate pt;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.showOptions();
        main.run();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new AppRoute());
        manualTester();
    }
    public void manualTester(){
        System.out.println("Manual tester executed");
        pt.sendBody("X");
    }
}
```

AppRoute.java:

```
private static class AppRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:tester")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Tester received message");
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you have to invoke direct:tester route somehow (e.g. from another route or from a producer)

Comment: it is not about invocation of the route. in this example `manualTester` method will never be invoked

Comment: I see. main.run() waits for the process to finish and it does not happen. Just move main.run() as a last line of your main method

Comment: `nullpointerexception` route is not being created with `main.run()` being set in the end (nullpointer while ProducerTemplate.sendbody method)

Comment: Never used this method of creating a route before, so forgive me if this seems like a noob question.  Are you not supposed to call the run method after adding the route builder to the Main object?

Comment: @Mithrand1r sorry I read over this again and saw that you already tried putting run at the end.  It looks to me like you are not scanning for annoatations, and so your producer template is not being injected, hence the null pointer exception when you call the sendbody method.  As an experiment, try creating a producer template manually and see if it works.

Comment: @ConMan you can find here http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html more info about .run() method